# How to force refresh layout to drawable values in java/android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm completely new to java, making a first game.
So, I need my Button "FLASH" to show my picture "on" after setting the background resources to it, currently it skips it and at the end of the code it changes to the "off" value, I have already tried several of the methods I could find online.

I have tried:

```
FLASH.invalidate;
----
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.parent);
vg.invalidate;
----
//setting FLASH as a togglebutton, with an xml file in drawable, which works when clicked
FLASH.setChecked(true);
----
FLASH.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState();
----
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.parent);
vg.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState();
----
FLASH.performClick;
----
//making giant loops and functions with if's or different calls to functions so it could refresh at the end of it
```

All to no avail

```
package net.myfreesites.httpmatthigast.test;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
//import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        game();
    }
    public void game()
    {
        final Button GO;
        GO = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Start);
        GO.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Button FLASH;
                FLASH = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Flash);
                try
                {
                    FLASH.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.on);
                    //Here I need something that forces the image "on" onto my FLASH-Button
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    FLASH.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.off);
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                }
                    catch (InterruptedException ignored)
                {
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

(This isn't the code of my game, but a single button, if I can make this one flash after clicking the GO-Button, I can make the ones in my game flash (which is the point of my whole game))

thanks in advance :)

Comment: See my answer below , please describe more what is your problem, i answer this with half understanding , hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

use ViewTreeObserver to refresh layout at runtime.set treeobserver on parent layout and change anything in the child view.
search  about View Tree Observer or find info [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html)

```
final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.YOUR_VIEW_ID);
ViewTreeObserver vto = layout.getViewTreeObserver(); 
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener (new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
@Override 
public void onGlobalLayout() {
    // refresh or add drawable here with condition
    layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this); 


} 
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the app crashes. Debugging I come to the conclusion it crashes because the layout (R.id.parent) is apparently null. I also tried (R.id.all) which also returns null. Actually... All layouts I can enter are null :(